# Kotlin Map<String, List<Object>> values are changed after toSortedMap call

Tags: dictionary, kotlin

I got such a map

```
Map<String, List<Object>>
```

when I use

```
map.toSortedMap(comparator)
```

and comparing values by keys I got sorted map but amount of objects in each value list is also changed (reduced). It's super strange. Under the hood toSortedMap method creates TreeMap with the given comparator, I don't know TreeMap internals but I assume that any map should not change values but only manipulate with the keys. Is this something that is ok for TreeMap or is it a bug in Kotlin library?

**Edit**
Code I get this issue on:

```
val categoriesKeys = listOf("key1", "key2", etc)
val categoriesKeysOrdersMap = mapOf("key1" to 0, "key2" to 1, etc)

val model = listOf(MyModel(..), MyModel(..), etc)

val categoryKeyToModelsMap = categoriesKeys
        .asSequence()
        .map { key ->
            key to model.filter {
                it.categories?.contains(key) == true
            }
        }
        .filter { it.second.isNotEmpty() }
        .toMap()
        .toSortedMap(compareBy { categoriesKeysOrdersMap[it] })
```

On toMap step I have the map I want but not sorted, but after toSortedMap  my data is messed up. Comparator compares by int value from categoriesKeysOrdersMap using key from category.

Comment: Please provide some code that reproduces this issue

Comment: Show your comparator. As [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-sorted-map.html) say: 
`Note that if the natural sorting order of keys considers any two keys of this map equal (this could happen if the equality of keys according to Comparable.compareTo is inconsistent with the equality according to Any.equals), only the value associated with the last of them gets into the resulting map.`

Comment: @gpunto I added the code.

Comment: We need code that we can compile and run to see the issue in action. The code you provided cannot be compiled and run because it misses information, like the `MyModel` class and how the `model` list is made. 
By only looking at the code you posted, the issue you are experimenting should not happen.